# How to color column cells according to the column values in DT::datatable in r

Tags: r, dt

According to [this link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html),  datatable can be colored by their value like heatmap.  But here the cells are colored according to values from all columns.

```
library(DT)
df = iris[1:4]
brks <- quantile(df, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
  {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

But what I need is to color column cells according to the values *for each column*.  Generally I think this is more useful. In reality each column might be in different scale.

Does anyone know how to achieve that *using DT package*? I need to color my table in my shiny app.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can change the `names(df)` to be the column or vector of columns of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for each column, you can calculate breaks, assign colors and apply a style:

```
library(DT)
library(viridis)
df = iris[1:4]

brks1 <- quantile(df$Sepal.Length, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
clrs1 <- viridis::viridis(n=length(brks1)+1, alpha=.5, direction = -1)

brks2 <- quantile(df$Petal.Length, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
clrs2 <- viridis::inferno(n=length(brks2)+1, alpha=.5, direction = -1)

datatable(df) %>% 
  formatStyle("Sepal.Length", backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks1, clrs1)) %>% 
  formatStyle("Petal.Length", backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks2, clrs2))
```